# When to use module.exports (Node.js) vs export (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project using JavaScript, Node.js and AWS Lambda. My question is "when should module.exports be used?".

I know `module.exports` is from Node.js, `export` is from JS, but can we use them interchangeably? (Apparently, `export`(JS) is used for between JS files, and `module.exports` is used in Lambda files.)

I really didn't find answers to explain exactly about this. Hope someone can help me out with understanding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use exports in nodejs but you have to set `"type": "module"` in the `package.json`. exports are newer and usually preferred

Comment: I know ```exports```  and ```module.exports``` can be used interchangeably - what about ```export```, though? (**not** ```exports```)

Comment: This is what I meant

Comment: Read the node documentation on commonjs and es modules. You should try to avoid mixing module systems unless you have to, and check out their [interoperability](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs).

Comment: They serve the same purpose but work differently. CJS modules are legacy, when you need to use them because ESM can't be used, you need that. CJS module.exports is translated to ESM default import when imported inside ESM